# AWS CLI and ECS query - HTTPSConnectionPool 443 error; Max retries exceeded; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Having some trouble with the aws ecs cli.

Found some suggestions that this error message might be to do with region but as you can see the region is set in my config, and if I add the option '--region eu-west-1' to the cli I still receive the same error.

> $ aws --version
>   
> > aws-cli/1.7.5 Python/2.7.9 Darwin/14.0.0
>
> $ aws configure list

```
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
  profile                <not set>             None    None
  access_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
  secret_key     ******************** shared-credentials-file
  region                eu-west-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

> $ aws ecs list-clusters
>   
> > HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ecs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by : [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Worth noting that the ec2 command is working just fine:

> $ aws ec2 describe-instances
>   {"Reservations": []}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon EC2 Container Service is currently only available in us-east-1.  From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html

> Customers accessing Amazon ECS during the preview should use the US East (N. Virginia) region.

Comment: Thanks @jamesls, missed that tiny little (but very important!) caveat in the docs! Kind regards, Andrew